# Transimpedence amplifier output from 0 to 3V

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog, output

I have this circuit configuration using the Lm324an op amp with a 5V rail (needs to be 5V) an infrared led and a photodiode. At the minute using a using a 1M resistor the output swings to rails when I place the light source closer to the photodiode however I would like the output to vary from 0 to 3V. How can I modify or at to the circuit to achieve this? I am also unsure what values of resistor and capacitance to pick. 
[image: circuit]

Comment: Use the schematic editor to create a proper schematic, please!  Also explain why you need 3V, what the output is feeding, output impedance requirements, and what you're trying to accomplish.  More information will only help us get you a good solution.

Comment: Reduce Rf? from 1Megohm to something lower. Or move the IR-LED further away. Or increase the IR-LED's series resistor value.

Comment: why not just feed the opamp 3v? it won't output any higher, and 3v is in-spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TIA low voltage has challenges:

- high diode pF at low voltage reverse bias.
- poor CM V input range
- poor output swing
- stray capacitance with 1 to 10M feedback
- lots of web designs avoid these constraints

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5129

Bias +in

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the output to vary from 0 to 3V.

- You could use a resistor potential divider at the output to reduce 5 volts to 3 volts.
- If your circuit has too much sensitivity then lowering the 1 Mohm to 100 kohm reduces sensitivity by 10 for instance. This might be a possible alternative solution

> I am also unsure what values of resistor and capacitance to pick.

The feedback resistor value sets the photo-gain of the circuit. If the photodiode produces (say) 1 uA for a given incident light power then the op-amp output will convert that to 1 volt when using a 1 Mohm resistor and 0.1 volts for a 100 kohm resistor.

The capacitor is used to reduce noise and is based on the capacitance of the photodiode. The bigger the PD capacitance, the greater the feedback capacitor needs to be to achieve the same noise levels. It's related to a thing called [noise gain](http://www.linear.com/solutions/5633).